# Freeform limit form access to certain member groups in CMS

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is there a setting somewhere to hide certain forms from certain members when they are logged into the CMS. The reason being is that, as with managing other sections/channels in Expression Engine, we need to limit member to edit only a one of the forms we have added eg. All forms are Marketing Request, Sales Request, General Enquiry but we what to have the Marketing Member Group to only have access to the Marketing Request form.

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if you're looking for that functionality in the CP (blocking access to specific forms per member group), that is currently not available. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on. :)
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

On the front-end, however, you can do this using regular conditionals. For example, if your group_id for "Marketing Member Group" is 7, then you could do something like this:

```
{if group_id == 7}
   /// Marketing Request form
{/if}
```